# update component in another xhtml form from Custom layout p:selectOneRadio not working

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

My xhtml is split in to Menu area (defaultMenu.xhtml) and Content area (defaultContent.xhtml).

The code for defaultMenu.xhtml is:

```
<h:form id="defaultmenuform">
    <p:outputPanel id="menupanel" class="contain auto-fixed-center">
        <p:panel id="pmenu" visible="#{phController.user.menuVisible}">
            <table id="stutable">
            <tr>
            <td width="15%">
                <p:outputLabel id="stuname" value="#{phController.phBean.studentName}" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <p:tabMenu activeIndex="#{param.selectedtab}">
                    <p:menuitem value="Home" outcome="phome" icon="ui-icon-star">
                        <f:param name="selectedtab" value="0" />
                    </p:menuitem>
                    <p:menuitem value="Bank" outcome="bhome" icon="ui-icon-person">
                        <f:param name="selectedtab" value="1" />
                    </p:menuitem>
                </p:tabMenu>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </p:panel>
    </p:outputPanel>
</h:form>
```

The defaultContent.xhtml actually displays the ph.xhtml content (as part of functional navigation) and the code is:

```
<ui:define name="content">

<f:event listener="#{phController.readPeople}" type="preRenderView">
</f:event>

<h:form id="form">

<p:selectOneRadio id="selstud" value="#{phController.phBean.ssSeq}" layout="custom">
    <p:ajax update=":defaultmenuform:parentmenupanel :defaultmenuform:stuname" listener="#{phController.onChangePerson}"/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{phController.selectStudents}" />
</p:selectOneRadio>

    <div style="width: 300px; float:left;">
        <p:dataGrid var="studentlist" value="#{phController.listStudent}" columns="1" rowIndexVar="stuindex">
            <p:panel header="" style="text-align:left">
                <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="width:100%">
                    <h:outputText value="#{studentlist.studentName}" />

                    <p:radioButton for=":form:selstud" itemIndex="#{stuindex}"/> Select

                 </h:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>
        </p:dataGrid>
    </div>

    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

The code for backing bean is:

```
    Map<String, Object> studentparam = new HashMap<>();
    studentparam.put("studentSeq", phBean.getSsSeq());

    lS = getBaseDAOService().readStudent("readStudent", studentparam);
    phBean.setStudentName(lS.get(0).getStudentFirstName() + " " + lS.get(0).getStudentLastName());
```

As you can see, I am calling the onChangeStu method to display the selected Student Name in defaultMenu.xhtml. I am using Custom Layout p:selectOneRadio in ph.xhtml and onClick trying to update a p:outputLabel in defaultMenu.xhtml.

The backing bean method gets invoked successfully and the value is also set in variable phController.phBean.studentName, but the update is not working. I also checked using view source and the id is “:defaultmenuform:stuname”, I also tried updating the menu panel ":defaultmenuform:menupanel”, but none of this works.

Not sure how to resolve this. Please suggest.

Including the structure of all .xhtmls

```
<h:body id="entirePageBody">
    <div id="page">

        <ui:insert name="header" >
            <ui:include src="/template/defaultHeader.xhtml" />
        </ui:insert>

        <ui:insert name="menu" >
            <ui:include src="/template/defaultMenu.xhtml" />
        </ui:insert>


        <div id="content_div" class="auto-fixed-center">
            <div id="content_div_padding" class="content-block"> 
                <ui:insert name="content" >
                    <ui:include src="/template/defaultContent.xhtml" />
                    <ui:debug hotkey="z" />
                </ui:insert>
        </div>
        </div>

        <ui:insert name="footer" >
            <ui:include src="/template/defaultFooter.xhtml" />
        </ui:insert>

   </div>
</h:body>
```

PhController.java:

public class PhController extends BaseController implements Serializable {

```
private List<Stud> listStudent;
private List selectStudents;
SelectItem option;
private PhBean phBean;
private Boolean menuVisible;

int counter = 0;

public PhController() {

    phBean = new PhBean();
}

public void readPeople() {

    listStudent = new ArrayList<Stud>();
    listStudent.add(new Stud(1, "John Miller"));
    listStudent.add(new Stud(2, "Scott Jackson"));

    selectStudents = new ArrayList();

    option = new SelectItem(listStudent.get(0).getStudentSeq(), "Select");
    selectStudents.add(option);

    option = new SelectItem(listStudent.get(1).getStudentSeq(), "Select");
    selectStudents.add(option);

    phBean.setSsSeq(String.valueOf(1));
    phBean.setSelectedName(listStudent.get(0).getStudentName());

    menuVisible = true;

}

public void onChangePerson() {

    phBean.setSelectedName(listStudent.get(1).getStudentName());
}

// Getters and Setters
```

}

PhBean.java:

public class PhBean implements Serializable {

```
private String ssSeq;
private String studName;    // Used to display the name in the Menu bar.
private String selectedName;

public PhBean() {
}

// Getters and Setters
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that in the `p:ajax` in `defaultContent.xhtml` the list of components to be updated should be separated with spaces only, no commas - so try changing this:

```
update=":defaultmenuform:menupanel, :defaultmenuform:stuname"
```

to this:

```
update=":defaultmenuform:menupanel :defaultmenuform:stuname"
```

**UPDATE**

I played with this a bit more and may have found a clue - please add the following code to `defaultmenuform`:

```
<p:messages autoUpdate="true" showDetail="true" />
```

This should help us tracking the reason for failed validation (in case failing validation is the root cause for you - as I said, I have rather limited possibility to reproduce this issue).

Anyway, when I selected some item in p:selectOneRadio, an error message like this appeared:

```
Conversion Error setting value 'test001.Student@4110c95c' for 'null Converter'.
```

And the root cause was on this row:

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="selstud" value="#{phController.phBean.ssSeq}" layout="custom">
```

`p:selectOneRadio` expects only `String` to be passed as a `value` - and `ssSeq` is very likely of a different type. Try to change the way `value` is populated to ensure it is always `String` - maybe a different attribute of the `phBean` or simply a brand new `String` one.

NOTE: if this doesn't help, maybe you could update your question with very simplified example of how `phController` and `phBean` could look like if we are to test it.

**UPDATE #2**

So you have explained there is a problem that you want to call `phController.readPeople` every time the page is loaded/refreshed, but instead it gets loaded with each and every Ajax request, thus overwriting the values.

In your `PhController` (it is a bean, right? session scoped?) you could add something like this (omitted `null` checks for the sake of readability):

```
public void readPeopleOnGet() {
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) ec.getRequest();
    String reqMethod = req.getMethod();

    if ("GET".equals(reqMethod)) {
        readPeople();
    }
}
```

With the above method you could keep this part of your `defaultContext.xhtml` in place, provided it is actually called (I assume so), just with the listener method changed:

```
<f:event listener="#{phController.readPeopleOnGet}" type="preRenderView">
</f:event>
```

The method `readPeopleOnGet` will still be called with every request to the page, but since Ajax requests are `POST`, it will only call `readPeople` when the page is loaded or refreshed as whole.

This may not be a "perfectly clean" solution, but seemed to work properly when I tested it.

**UPDATE #3**

Well, since you use PrimeFaces, it would be possible to identify Ajax call also this way:

```
public void readPeopleOnGet() {
    RequestContext rc = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();

    if (!rc.isAjaxRequest()) {
        readPeople();
    }
}
```

But if I got your point from latest comments, you want to only run `readPeople` when the page is loaded for the very first time - so the following part could be even better for that.

You didn't answer if `PhController` is actually a bean, but I assume it is (there were no annotations visible from the code you posted). You may try making it `@SessionScoped`:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class PhController extends BaseController implements Serializable {
// the rest of the PhController goes here...
```

Then you could add something like this to the `PhController`:

```
@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    readPeople();
}
```

The annotation `@PostConstruct` ensures the method `init` is called exactly once after the bean was created. You can continue calling the method `readPeople` from other places as necessary, while removing both the `<f:event ... />` and `readPeopleOnGet` as these will no longer be needed.

Comment: Sorry it didn't work. I also tried with just :defaultmenuform:stuname and just :defaultmenuform:menupanel - both didn't work as well. For additional clarity, I have also included the overall layout of all .xhtmls if that helps to answer.

Comment: Another option is to remove the leading colon from both identifiers as you are refering to the exact IDs: `update="defaultmenuform:menupanel defaultmenuform:stuname"` - I can't really test it right now, but if this doesn't help, I will try to check this once I'm back from work. Also verify if the IDs are correct by checking the generated output.

Comment: Removing leading colon also didn’t work. Throws Exception: Cannot find component with expression "defaultmenuform:menupanel" referenced from "form:selstud".

Comment: Checking the output generated, this is the line for the p:outputLabel in defaultMenu.xhtml – 

<label id="defaultmenuform:stuname" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget">Student-1 FName LName</label>

Comment: This is the line for the <p:radioButton for=":form:selstud" itemIndex="#{stuindex}"/> Select
<input id="form:selstud:0" name="form:selstud" type="radio" value="1" checked="checked" onchange="PrimeFaces.ab({s:'form:selstud',e:'valueChange',p:'form:selstud',u:'defaultmenuform:menupanel defaultmenuform:stuname'});">

Comment: Two observations:
Obv a) For the defaultContent.xhtml, View page source on right click is still showing html code generated for the first screen (the login.xhtml page). I took the above generated output using Inspect Element.

Comment: Obv b) I couldn’t see any code generated for 

 <p:selectOneRadio id="selstud" value="#{parentHomeController.parentHomeBean.selectedStudentSeq}" layout="custom">
  <p:ajax update=":defaultmenuform:parentmenupanel :defaultmenuform:stuname" listener="#{parentHomeController.onChangeStudent}"/>
  <f:selectItems value="#{parentHomeController.selectStudents}" />
 </p:selectOneRadio>

I believe that’s the way it works, that is, <p:selecOneRadio> gets generated as <input type=”radio”.........>

Comment: After some testing in my "simplified environment" I found out that - again, at least for me - there was a validation failing. Near the end of response there was something like this: `<extension ln="primefaces" type="args">{"validationFailed":true}</extension>`

So, if this is your case and you are sure the validation may be skipped for this action, consider adding `immediate="true"` to your `p:ajax`

Comment: In this case, one of the radio buttons will always be selected by default, so validation is not needed. I tried adding immediate="true" but issue still continues.

Comment: I have updated my answer with additional steps that could help us to debug this issue. Hopefully that will reveal what is the root cause.

Comment: I have also included p:messages autoUpdate="true" showDetail="true" /> in defaultmenuform. Yes, phController.phBean.ssSeq was actually an int. I have now changed it to String and it still doesn't work.

I will get the simplified version of phController and phBean shortly.

Comment: Did further investigation and realised that a method initially used to load the screen from ph.xhml is getting called after this AJAX call, so the value is getting overwritten, which makes it look like 'Update' is not working. I have updated the ph.xhtml code above. Now need to investigate how to execute this readPeople() method whenever the ph.xhtml is loaded/navigated to but not executed for any AJAX calls within the Page. Please suggest.

Comment: Tried using <f:metadata> <f:viewAction action="#{parentHomeController.readPeople}" /> </f:metadata>
instead of <f:event listener="#{phController.readPeople}" type="preRenderView"> </f:event> thinking metadata will load only once but throwing exception
Exception type: class javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException
Exception message: The class 'com.innovate.ui.test.PhController' does not have the property 'readPeople'.

The ph.xhtml is called on click of a commandbutton in the previous screen

Comment: I see. I have updated my answer with respect to the new discovery you made.

Comment: Sorry, the request method always seem to be POST. The first screen displayed in login screen (login.xhtml) within the defaultContent.xhtml. Then on cliking Submit, the ph.xhtml is loaded in defaultContext.xhtml.
Here is the Login commandbutton code:
   <p:panelGrid id="mainPanelGrid" columns="1">
    <f:facet name="footer">
     <p:commandButton id="LoginButton" value="Login" update="mainPanelGrid"
      action="#{loginController.executeProcess}" icon="ui-icon-check"
      process="@form" />
    </f:facet>
   </p:panelGrid>
The executeProcess returns String "ph" to navigate to ph.xhtml

Comment: Seems we are slowly moving towards the solution :-) Please re-check my answer, I addded 3rd update to it.

Comment: Sounds like a solution, will try that tonight. Sorry missed to respond about the PhController, yes it is a bean with viewScoped
"@ManagedBean"
"@ViewScoped"
public class PhController extends BaseController implements Serializable {

Comment: Adding @PostConstruct throws 
BUILD FAILURE
Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.2.Final:deploy (default-cli) on project innovate: Deployment failed and was rolled back. -> [Help 1]
For now I have kept a Boolean variable in an object in session and used that to call this method for the first time.

Comment: came across this website http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-postconstruct-and-predestroy-example/
on how to use @PostConstruct, but I am not using Spring, how do I set <context:annotation-config /> in Primeface context?

Comment: It's not Spring-related, but coming from JavaEE - you just need to import `javax.annotation.PostConstruct` to be able to use it.

Comment: Yes that is imported, but this error comes when I do Build using Maven.

Comment: Hi, sorry I still haven't cracked this yet, but progressing currently with the Boolean bean. Thanks for all your time on this. Appreciate it.